# How to change my <select> out with <input> to use with barcode scanner

Tags: php, jquery

I'm about to change a script, and right know the script are using an `<select>` with one options and echo to be used to show the products.

Now I'll like to change the `<select>` to a `<input>` so I can scan a barcode, and the information from the product should be added to the DB as it is right now, but I'm lost, I have used several hours to figuere out how to change it, I thought the solution was to use a hidded  but then I can't add the first knowen product to my list.

Could someone please help me? :)

I've tried to use more  boxes to get the products, but that was a big mess.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Product Name</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="prod_name" tabindex="1" autofocus required>
      <?php
        $branch=$_SESSION['branch'];
        $cid=$_REQUEST['cid'];

        include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');

        $query2=mysqli_query($con,"select * from product where branch_id='$branch' order by prod_name")or die(mysqli_error());

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['prod_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['prod_name']." Available(".$row['prod_qty'].")";?></option>
          <?php }?>
    </select>

      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cid;?>" required>   
    </div><!-- /.form group -->
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Quantity</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control pull-right" id="date" name="qty" placeholder="Quantity" tabindex="2" value="1"  required>
      </div><!-- /.input group -->
    </div><!-- /.form group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date"></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" tabindex="3" name="addtocart">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code should be changed to use a `<input>` or something simular, so I can use a barcode scanner to add my items to a list.

Comment: Replacing the select field with a text input of the same name should be trivial. (Show us what you tried in that regard, so that we can see if you messed that up somehow.) Whether this will work of course depends upon what exactly it is you are reading using your barcode scanner. Currently, the option value that gets submitted, is `$row['prod_id']`. If your barcode scanner does not read that kind of product IDs, but something else, then of course this won’t work, in that case you’d need to implement some sort of translation between the two.

Comment: I've tried to add this one: `<input class="form-control" name="prod_name" tabindex="1" autofocus required onchange="this.form.submit()">` But without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get my result was:

I changed the prod_id to be the barcode, and on scan the form is submitted to a temp_db, to show every items, and then added a "finish db" called inStock, and everything was as it should be! :)

/Kenneth